# How do you gift the Battle Pass to other players if you already own the Battle Pass?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

They've suppposedly added the ability to gift Battle Passes to other players -- I saw this feature before I bought the Battle Pass in Season 10, and then bought it for myself. Now the option to gift it no longer seems to be anywhere, not on the Battle Pass screen or even the Item Store.

How do you gift the Battle Pass to other players if you already own the Battle Pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the Battle Pass screen in Season X, there will be a yellow button just like the buy Battle Pass button but instead, it'll say **Gift Battle Pass** and it will also have a price written below it. If you press the button regularly on PC/Laptop and Mobile, or press <kbd>Y</kbd> on Xbox, it'll ask you to confirm your purchase. **IMPORTANT:** You need to be friends with the person and have them added for more than a week before you can gift them **anything**.

Comment: An anonymous user has attempted to ask a question about this post through a suggested edit: *Do you have to have your account verified before you gift?*